# Get nested document using mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

How can I find nested document using mongo db _id.

```
{  
    "_id": "5aead7541b5cd15fb70b4c61",
    "name": "myconversation",
    "nodes": [{
            "_id": "5aead7541b5cd15fb70b4c62",
            "plugin_id": "text_card",
            "title": "First Card",
            "text": "my text"
        }]
}
```

Comment: Hi Chaitanya Thakre, and welcome to Stack Overflow I _think_ that the answer to your question is to use dot notation, but it's hard to be sure because you haven't included much detail in your question. Could you [edit] it to include the query results you're hoping to get, and what query or queries you have tried so far and why they aren't working?

Comment: Do you mean to find the `_id` in the array? Or the `_id` in the root of the document? More details needed

Comment: Need little more explanation

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to query inside the array nodes with _id:

db.collection.find( { nodes: {$elemMatch: { _id: "5aead7541b5cd15fb70b4c62" }} } )

Answer (score 0):

You can data like below.

db.collection.find({ 'nodes._id': "5aead7541b5cd15fb70b4c62" });